# Calculating chance of DOT effect being active

Tags: probability-theory

Trying to calculate a DPS from a periodic effect that has *P(A)* chance to be applied every second and if applied deals damage for *n* seconds.

Event *A* happens with a probability of *P(A)*. If it happens, then in the next *n* iterations event *B* happens with a probability of 1. If there is an infinite amount of iterations, what is the probability of event *B* happening at any given iteration?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? What is DPS? DOT?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think these are game development terms. DPS stands for "Damage Per Second", and DOT stands for "Damage Over Time". I'm not 100% sure though, and it would be nice if the OP added more context for those who aren't familliar.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context and explain what you are working on that requires this machanic (where the problem comes from)? Perhaps explain what DPS and DOT mean for those who don't know?

Comment: Can DPS effects overlap with each other? In other words, if A triggers at time=1 sec and at time=2 secs, do the B effects stack at time=3 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly how this process works...

The game alternates between periods where damage is applied, which always have length $n$, and periods where there is no damage, which have random length. The length of the non-damage periods follows a geometric distribution, which means the expected value of their length is $(1-P(A))/P(A)$. It follows that the long-run proportion of intervals for which damage is being applied is
$$
\frac{n}{n+(1-P(A))/P(A)}=\frac{P(A)\cdot n}{P(A)\cdot n+1-P(A)}
$$